# To create a class Vector which has no specific dimension at the beginning, create a method in class allowing to add a dimension to the vector

Tags: c++, function, class, vector, compare

I know how to create a class Vector which has a specific dimension for example if it was 3D i would put in the private 3 doubles x,y, and z. However, I want to create a class called vector of unknown dimension, having the methods : increase - allowing to add a dimension to the vector and a value to this new dimension. 
print - to print the vector out 
compare - to compare 2 different vectors together.

So my approach would be as follows: 
i would create a vector in private:

```
class Vector {
private: vector<double>vect; //
public: void print() const; 
        bool compare(Vector const& v) const; 
        vector<double> increase(double& a); 
};
void Vector::print()const{ 
for(size_t i(0); i < vect.size(); ++i) { cout << i << endl; }}

bool Vector::compare(Vector const& v) const{ 
for(size_t i(0); i < v.size(); ++i){
    for(size_t j(0); j < vect.size(); ++j){
if(v[i] == vect[j]) { return true; }

vector<double> Vector::increase(double& a){ 
vect = vect.push_back(a); 
return vect; }
```

Would this be incorrect or where is the mistake here? could you please let me know what i could do to improve this or if i went wrong somehow.

Thanks

Comment: If you want a blow-by-blow critique of your code you are probably better off posting to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As a general idea, I don't see anything wrong with using `std::vector` in this way, if you really need to be able to change the dimensions of your `Vector` at runtime.

But your code is riddled with compilation errors and logic errors. Particularly your `compare` function. So I assume you just want us to treat it as pseudo-code and comment on the general idea.